# Вывод среднего значения с масива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть такой массив данных

```
$test_array = array(
    "test_array" => array(
        "0" => array(
            "test" => array(
                "green" => array(
                    "num" => 1
                ) ,
                "yellow" => array(
                    "num" => 2
                ) ,
                "blue" => array(
                    "num" => 3
                )
            )
        ) ,
        "1" => array(
            "test" => array(
                "green" => array(
                    "num" => 4
                ) ,
                "yellow" => array(
                    "num" => 5
                ) ,
                "blue" => array(
                    "num" => 6
                )
            )
        ) ,
        "2" => array(
            "test" => array(
                "green" => array(
                    "num" => 7
                ) ,
                "yellow" => array(
                    "num" => 8
                ) ,
                "blue" => array(
                    "num" => 9
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
foreach ($test_array['test_array'] as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value['test'] as $k => $v){

    }
}
```

Требуется вывести среднее значение всех цветов
подскажите правильное решение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сперва получить массив всех чисел, потом сложить все числа и поделить их сумму на их количество:

```
$nums = [];

array_walk_recursive($test_array, function($item, $key) use(&$nums){
    $nums[] = $item;
});

echo array_sum($nums) / count($nums);
```

---

[См. демо](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1ce48354a513a80dbd69c916d2bc427fa98ac8cf)